# Magento 2 : How to fire custom ajax before add to cart ajax fire in product detail page?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, requirejs, ajaxaddtocart

I have created custom extension and how to fire custom ajax before
 add to cart ajax fire in product detail page from my custom module.
 I don't want to override js in theme level. please suggest any
 solution

Comment: I've given answer, if any doubts please comment below.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom module (suppose my custom module is `Anshu_Custom`), add `requirejs-config.js` under `Anshu/Custom/view/frontend`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'Anshu_Custom/js/add-to-cart-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now create your mixin js file `add-to-cart-mixin.js` under `Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/web/js`

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
    'use strict';

    return function(catalogAddToCart){ // this function receives the return value of the mixin target
        $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', catalogAddToCart, {
            submitForm: function(form) {
                console.log('Working');
        // your custom code
                return this._super(form);
            }
        });
        return catalogAddToCart; // always mixins has to return a function
    };
});
```